# Particles with Render as Object not shown in Viewport and Render

Tags: rendering, objects, particles

I have a simple particle system that is supposed to imitate rain. So I formed a simple raindrop and selected the raindrop for "Render as". But now I have the problem that the raindrops are not displayed in the finished render. They are only displayed in the viewport if I have selected "Viewport Display" -> Display as Point. With Display as Rendered, it is also not shown in the viewport. I just don't understand why .. I have attached a simplified file and would be very grateful if someone could take a quick look at it!

[image]

Comment: it looks like it has to do with the Children > Interpolated option, I'm not sure how it is supposed to work? It doesn't seem to work from what I see...

Comment: Oh yes you are right! Hmm really strange 

Answer (score 2):

If you use *Particles > Hair*, you need to enable *Render > Extra > Parent Particles* to see the parents.

If you use *Particles > Emitter*, as it's the case here, *Children > Interpolated* doesn't seem to work (unless someone tells otherwise, I guess it's still here because you may want to switch from *Hair* to *Emitter*).